# Create a Bulk products using rest api with rabbitMq custom queue in magento 2.3 beta

Tags: product, module, magento2.3, queue, rabbit-mq

How to publish message to rabbitmq and read message in consumer and create a bulk products in magento while running custom queue in rabbitmq.

I want to create custom module in magento 2.3 beta to track the publisher message and processing message in consumer

Comment: Please it's urgent for me.i am trying but bulk api class not found in vendor , where it is going in vendor which files. please provide any links and etc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently implementing bulk API for products and i have created custom module for it. I had to create custom module because i receive product data from a source does not have all attributes i wanted to create a product in magento. In my module i have a function that will push product data to RabbitMQ. My function will look as below:

```
private function bulkPublish($products, $topic)
{
    $inputProcessed = [];
    foreach ($products as $key => $singleEntityParams) {
        $inputProcessed[$key] = $this->inputProcessor->process(
            'Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface',
            'save',
            $singleEntityParams
        );

    }
    $result = null;

    try {

        $result = $this->massSchedule->publishMass($topic, $inputProcessed)->getBulkUuid();
        //$result = $this->massSchedule->publishMass($topic, $inputProcessed)->getBulkUuid();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();

    }
    return $result;

}
```

**Where:** 
**$this->inputProcessor** = InpMagento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor;
**$this->massSchedule** = Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Model\MassSchedule;
**$topic** = async.magento.catalog.api.productrepositoryinterface.save.put ;
**$products** = Formatted data based on requirement for magento API

Following command should read message from RabbitMq:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all
```

You might run this as a cron job or anyway you want.

I know this is late to answer but adding here so that other can use if they want.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Have already developed 1year back that above task.